# Big RAM usage - Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04

screenshot of htop here
[image: screenshot of htop here]

I installed Ubuntu 2 days ago and I saw that my RAM usage is big. I have restarted it multiple times. I saw at others that their RAM usage was 500-600MB, while mine is big af.

Please help, I switched to linux because it's lightweight but don't see any improvement. Elementary OS was like this for 1 or 2 days, but then I saw that the RAM usage was very good (like 600mb)

Sorry for bad formatting.

Answer (score 2):

From your htop screenshot, I can see you are running both Spotify and Discord. From my experience, these apps will use a lot of memory, even under Linux.

You might be able to resolve the issue by following the recommendations on their forums.

After looking a bit around I myself have not found anything that might solve the issue for the Linux version of Spotify. Though, I did find a solution for the Windows version where they disabled hardware acceleration [here](https://community.spotify.com/t5/Desktop-Windows/Spotify-uses-too-much-RAM/td-p/1133963).

As both Spotify and Discord use chromium as a backend this solution might also work for Discord.

Comment: And as I'm unable to comment on your question, could you filter your htop on memory usage? This might reveal another application that is using a lot of memory.

Comment: Still, I mean I had on elementary OS 750mb with Discord on.

Comment: Wdym by "filter your htop by memory usage"?

Comment: @NarcisMoraru When having htop open, click on MEM% using your mouse pointer. This will sort all processes based on their memory usage. Also, could you "Hide userland process threads"? You can find this in F2(Setup) -> "Display options" -> "Hide userland process threads".

Comment: You've got Brave, Discord and Spotify. That's 3 chromium memory hogs and 4 GB of RAM, Linux distributions can be lightweight but applications you run on them won't magically decrease consumption when they're not designed for efficiency.